# Infinite loop viewDidAppear on launch

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, xcode8

I have to refactor an App and move legacy code in a framework.

I have done the first part of the migration. But when i start my app, i have an infinite loop on the first screen

[image]

The default ViewController is a simple UIViewController with no custom class.

Comment: what does the function `fira_viewDidAppear:` implemented in the category `UIViewController(FIRAScreenClassName)` look like?

Comment: It's an implementation made by firebase.

Comment: I think you should look for code that swizzle viewDidAppear method for UIViewController.

Comment: what does your `UIViewController` `viewDidAppear:` function look like?

Comment: I haven't touch this function. I think there is an extension in Firebase Framework and maybe i have badly implemented this Framework. So i have an infite loop...

Comment: Are you calling`[self viewDidAppear:animated]` instead of `[super viewDidAppear:animated]` ?

Comment: I don't used any custom UIViewController.